# Do "twice as high xxxxx as" , "twice as high" and "twice higher" mean the same thing?

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference, sentence-meaning

What do the following sentences actually mean? 
Are they the same in meaning?

> 1. The cost of living is **twice as high in New York as** it is in Tokyo.
> 2. The cost of living in New York is **twice as high** in Tokyo.
> 3. The cost of living in New York is **twice higher** than in Tokyo.
> 4. The cost of living in New York is **two times higher** than in Tokyo.

If they have the same meaning, then can I actually use them as a basis for composing other sentences having the same meanings? Such as:

> 1a. Your child is a hundred times as adorable as your pet dog.
>   1b. Your child is a hundred times adorable than your pet dog.
>
> 2a. Her room is twice as large as mine.
>   2b. Her room is twice larger than mine.

Comment: This is clearly not a proofreading question.

Answer (score 5):

Let C<sub>NY</sub> = the cost of living in New York, and C<sub>T</sub> = the cost of living in Tokyo.

#### Sentences Nos. 1 & 2:

> The cost of living is twice as high in New York as it is in Tokyo.
> The cost of living in New York is twice as high in Tokyo.

these mean: C<sub>NY</sub> = 2 × C<sub>T</sub>
<sup>e.g., if it costs $500 per week to live in Tokyo, it would cost $1000 per week to live in NY</sup>

---

#### Sentence No. 3:

> The cost of living in New York is twice higher than in Tokyo.

I would say this one is a non-standard way of making the comparison, and, of your options, it would be better to avoid this one.

---

#### Sentence No. 4:

> The cost of living in New York is two times higher than in Tokyo.

Again, that's C<sub>NY</sub> = 2 × C<sub>T</sub>, but remove the *than*:

> The cost of living in New York is two times higher in Tokyo.

and it means 2 × C<sub>NY</sub> = C<sub>T</sub>

<sup>e.g., if it costs $500 per week to live in Tokyo, it would cost $250 per week to live in NY</sup>

---

#### Sentences Nos. 1a & 1b:

> Your child is a hundred times as adorable as your pet dog.
> Your child is a hundred times adorable than your pet dog.

The first one is okay, but the second one needs an extra word:

> Your child is a hundred times **more** adorable than your pet dog.

---

#### Sentences Nos. 2a & 2b:

> Her room is twice as large as mine.
> Her room is twice larger than mine.

Once again, I'd avoid the second one. However, when dealing with cost, we can use the expression *twice as much as*:

> The cost of living in New York is *twice as much as* in Tokyo. (C<sub>NY</sub> = 2 × C<sub>T</sub>)

Comment: Brainfreezeeeeeee! Examples are clear and right but don't you think there are too many of them? Still awesome answer.

Comment: @Berker - Too many of them? I only addressed the ones explicitly provided by the O.P. (Nonetheless, I've taken your comment as good feedback, and changed the headers to make that more evident now.)

Comment: Option 2, "the cost of X in Y is twice as high in Z" is a very awkward phrasing that I would never expect to hear; I would call it improper.  If I try to parse it out normally, it comes out as something like "living in New York is twice as expensive if you're actually living in New York in Tokyo".

Comment: The "add one word" analysis seems incorrect to me.  Also, examples 2 and 3 risk having the user think that CNY = 3 × CT.

Comment: This does not seem right. When x is twice as high as y, that means the value of x is equal to 2y. I'm not sure how you got the opposite equasion out of any of these sentences.

Comment: @lea - You're right; my algebra was terrible! :^) I don't know how I got some of these turned around in my head, but apparently I did. If you would, please see if my edited answer seems more accurate.

Comment: @JR you did well it's just for some people it would be hard to understand. You got to keep it simple for anyone to see the point. I already got it but as a programmer I thought it should be simpler.."more user friendly"

Comment: @David - Thanks; nice catch. You're right about the "than" in that last yellow block, so I've removed it. I had no idea this question would be so hard to explain when I started on it – I guess some answers shouldn't be composed until _after_ the first cup of coffee! I surely didn't mean to dispense such erroneous advice, and I'm glad you brought it to my attention so I could fix it.

Comment: @David - I don't think the first sentence stands on its own very well, either, but I think it could be used in a larger context: _Sure, it's expensive living in New York, but the cost of living [in New York] is twice as much in Tokyo._

Comment: @David - I think I may have messed it up again. I'm starting to regret ever trying to answer this question. I wish someone else would leave an answer, so I could delete mine.  :^/

Comment: @David - That would be kind of you, and I'd take no offense.

Comment: @ JR - Thank you for taking time to answer my query but yes, I agree with Berker. Maybe simpler sentences or sample reworded sentences can be used to explain the meaning. For some people who can better understand equations, they may be able to get it but for an English learner like me, I struggled a bit to understand the equation. But at least, I was able to understand some.